# Simple Php Namespace Class not Found

Tags: php, namespaces

This code

```
<?php
namespace Utilities;

use Utilities\PFactory;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
global $mylink; 

$checker = new PFactory();
$aProvider = $checker->getProvider(PFactory::ER);
```

where the class `Utilities\PFactory` is in the `./utilities/PFactory.php` file, gives the exception `Class PFactory not found`.
The IDE does not complain the `use` statement.

Why? Shall I use the require statement?

Comment: Are you using an autoloader? The `use` mechanism doesn't load anything for you, it just defines aliases.

Comment: You don't need `use` for classes that are under the same namespace as the current file. Other than that, as @AlexHowansky pointed out, you need to load the file somehow. Either by manually including/requiring the classes or use some autoloader.

Comment: Thank you! I completely confused the meaning of "use". Thank you again.